# Spring Security Principal transformation

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-security

Is there a way to transform a Spring Security Principal before it is injected in a RestController method?

Let's say I have defined the following class:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {
    @GetMapping("/test")
    public void getWithPrincipalA(@AuthenticationPrincipal PrincipalTypeA a) {
        ...
    }

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public void getWithPrincipalB(@AuthenticationPrincipal PrincipalTypeB b) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I know that these controller methods are ambiguous and I could do several things to solve that, but what I would rather do is transform the `@AuthenticationPrincipal` to some type I can define myself. The result would become something like:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {
    @GetMapping("/test")
    public void getWithTransformedPrincipal(@AuthenticationPrincipal MyTransformedPrincipal principal) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now I basically could define a single controller for several different authentication principals, without having to change the API.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Why? Why not just create a single method and dispatch yourself?

Comment: What kind of transformation are you talking about with what goal?

Comment: The `@AuthenticationPrincipal` is injected by Spring Security, but when you have different authentication mechanisms (cookie, token, etc) the `Principal` could be different. My rest API will be the same, though. If I could catch the different `Principal`s and convert them to a generic one that my `RestController` could handle, I wouldn't have to duplicate my controller methods.

Comment: In my previous comment I misunderstood your comment. I would do what M. Deinum suggests. Transform the principal within the controller method and dispatch that generic principal to others.

Comment: I don't care, that's the thing. I have different platforms my app lands on (WebSphere, PCF) and I would like them to use a shared `Principal`, although the authentication schemes are completely different.

Comment: I could pass `Authentication` or `Principal` to my controller method and do the transformation there, true. I would have liked to keep my controller method lean and put the logic in some handler, but if that's not possible I would go for this.

Comment: You could ultimately use a argument resolver to get the authication principal from the security context and transform it from there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183945/discussion-between-bart-and-dormouse).

Comment: Just get the regular `Principal` or `Authentication` instead of your specific typed one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too keep things simple and transparant you could simply transform the principal in your controller method and dispatch the generic principal from there.

```
@RestController
public class MyController {
    @GetMapping("/test")
    public void getWithTransformedPrincipal(@AuthenticationPrincipal Principal principal) {
        GenericPrincipal generic = PrincipalTransformer.transform(principal);
        doSomethingWithPrincipal(generic);
    }
}
```

Comment: Any chance of adding the argument resolver solution as an alternative?

Comment: I would rather not. Not because I'm unwilling. More because I think that it would distract from the more obvious and simple solution.

Comment: Right. Although that was the original question :)